# PHP MySQL insert not working

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry if it's a quite simple problem. I am not too experienced with web languages.
Basically, it doesn't work.

```
$insert=
(
  "INSERT INTO phpbb_members ".
  "(emailAddress, uid, valid, firstandlast, propic, memberName) ".
  "VALUES ($me['email'], $uid, 1, $me['name'], $propic, $newuser)"
);
mysql_query($insert) or die('Error, insert query failed');
```

Comment: have you tried just running the query using something like phpmyadmin? That may give you some more insight. Perhaps you have a column name typo or you're missing a column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem may be in the way you've laid out the information to be inserted.

This should work:

```
$insert=("INSERT INTO phpbb_members (emailAddress, uid, valid, firstandlast, propic, memberName)
VALUES ('$me[email]', '$uid', '1', '$me[name]', '$propic', '$newuser')");
        mysql_query($insert) or die('Error, insert query failed');
```

Hope it helps!

EDIT: I'm pretty sure the information to be inserted has to be inside `' '`.

Comment: Thanks this fixed the problem, I hate PHP and all its ' :(

Answer (score 5):

```
$insert="INSERT INTO phpbb_members (emailAddress, uid, valid, firstandlast, propic, memberName)
VALUES ('".$me['email']."', $uid, 1, '".$me['name']."', '$propic', $newuser)";
```

Missing singular quotes (for strings [varchar, char, text, etc]) and you need to close your quotes and concatenate when referencing an array.  The above assumed $uid and $newuser are stored numerically in the DB.

Comment: Exactly, you can't use $me['email'] inside double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

If you'll use the following for testing, it will show you the error:

```
mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error()."<br />".$insert);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$insert=("INSERT INTO phpbb_members (emailAddress, uid, valid, firstandlast, propic, memberName) 
VALUES ($me['email'], $uid, 1, $me['name'], $propic, $newuser)");
```

Do wee need those extra brackets in the beginning and end?
Try to remove it  and execute.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Person";
mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$insert=("INSERT INTO phpbb_members (emailAddress, uid, valid, firstandlast, propic, memberName)
VALUES ('".$me['email']."','". $uid."',1,'". $me['name']."','" .$propic."','". $newuser."')");
mysql_query($insert) or die('Error, insert query failed');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code,

```
 $insert=("INSERT INTO phpbb_members (emailAddress, uid, valid, firstandlast, propic, memberName) VALUES ('{$me['email']}', '{$uid}', '1', '{$me['name']}', '{$propic}', '{$newuser}')");
mysql_query($insert) or die('Error, insert query failed');
```